# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS mysql failed to start

Tags: 12.04, mysql, apparmor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't start mysql - mysql respawning too fast, stopped](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127264/cant-start-mysql-mysql-respawning-too-fast-stopped)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server which was running OK along with MySQL service 
,i had to reboot the server without any changes made to system and since then MySQL refuse to run.
i have following error message below
Please advice
Thanks

```
 22.022845] type=1400 audit(1349176528.410:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=793 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct  2 13:15:28 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   22.474857] init: mysql main process (876) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:15:28 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   22.474901] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Oct  2 13:15:29 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   23.214984] init: mysql post-start process (878) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:15:29 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   23.446895] init: mysql main process (946) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:15:29 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   23.446937] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Oct  2 13:15:30 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   24.254699] init: mysql post-start process (947) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:15:30 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   24.489266] init: mysql main process (984) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:15:30 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   24.489307] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
Oct  2 13:15:58 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   51.421278] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (758) killed by TERM signal
Oct  2 13:16:24 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   77.482282] audit_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed
Oct  2 13:16:24 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   77.482286] type=1400 audit(1349176584.205:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1613 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct  2 13:16:24 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   77.722406] init: mysql main process (1617) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:16:24 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   77.722450] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Oct  2 13:16:25 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   78.522680] init: mysql post-start process (1618) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:16:25 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   78.531120] type=1400 audit(1349176585.253:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1655 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct  2 13:16:25 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   78.764720] init: mysql main process (1659) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:16:25 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   78.764762] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Oct  2 13:16:26 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   79.559925] init: mysql post-start process (1660) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:16:26 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   79.568938] type=1400 audit(1349176586.293:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1698 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct  2 13:16:26 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   79.811874] init: mysql main process (1702) terminated with status 1
Oct  2 13:16:26 IT-SRV-MN12 kernel: [   79.811914] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

Comment: i tried it didn't work , is there a way to reinstall Mysql without loos existing databases and settings? Thanks